# How to detect swipe on a key in android soft keyboard

Tags: android

How to detect swipe action on a key in android soft keyboard? 
For a example lets say a user "swipe up" on letter "j" in the keyboard. How to detect it as a "swipe up" event which triggered on letter "j"?

Comment: Whats your aim behind doing this ??

Comment: I am developing av app to extend the messaging functionalities based on user events on keyboard and for that as one requirement I need to detect above event

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39200117/1293492

Answer (score 1):

> How to detect swipe action on a key in android soft keyboard?

Write your own soft keyboard.

Input method editors (a.k.a., soft keyboards) are implemented by other apps. Not every soft keyboard will even have *keys*. Hence there is no API whereby soft keyboards could report swipe events on keys, let alone rules forcing soft keyboard implementers to report on swipe events.

Comment: even though I am writing own keyboard, how to address above problem? How to identify such events?

Comment: @Buddy: I have no implemented an `InputMethodService` and kin. I would presume that you can respond to touch events there the same way you would in a regular activity.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone still struggling to achieve this here is my code:

````
public class KeyboardInput extends InputMethodService implements KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener {

    private KeyboardView keyboardView;
    private Keyboard keyboard;
    
    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    Boolean swipeUp = false;
    Boolean swipeDown = false;

    @SuppressLint({"InflateParams", "ClickableViewAccessibility"})
    @Override
    public View onCreateInputView() {
        keyboardView = (KeyboardView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.keyboard,null);
        View inputView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.keyboard, null);
        keyboardView = inputView.findViewById(R.id.keyboard_view); // Make sure to replace 'keyboardView' with the actual ID of your KeyboardView in the XML layout

        keyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.qwerty);
        keyboardView.setKeyboard(keyboard);
        keyboardView.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this);

        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new GestureListener());

        keyboardView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                return false; // Return false to allow the touch event to propagate
            }
        });

        return inputView;
    }
    
    public void onPress(int primaryCode) {
        //here check which key is touched first or where swipe is started
    }
    
    
    public class GestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
            @Override
            public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
                float distanceY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
                if (Math.abs(distanceY) > 100 && Math.abs(velocityY) > 100) {
                    if (distanceY < 0) {
                        swipeUp = true;
                    }
                    else if (distanceY > 0){
                        swipeDown = true;
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
} ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Are you writing own keyboard? If not, your app will not be informed on how user behaved on IME area.