# How to change keyboard layout by swipe left or right space key in custom keyboard

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-input-method, soft-keyboard

I made an android `custom keyboard`.

I want to use swiping on `Space key` on the keyboard for changing keyboard layout to show next language layout.

How can i do that?

I used bellow class:

```
public class KeyboardIMS extends InputMethodService implements KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener
{ ...}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by override touchEvent like this :

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {

float x = e.getX();
float y = e.getY();

    switch (e.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        mIsDown = true;
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

        float dx = x - mPreviousX;
        float dy = y - mPreviousY;

        // Here you can try to detect the swipe. It will be necessary to
        // store more than the previous value to check that the user move constantly in the same direction
        detectSwipe(dx, dy);

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        mIsDown = false;
        break;
}

mPreviousX = x;
mPreviousY = y;
return true;}
```

Comment: hi Himani. tnx for your answer.
but I want to see a complete sample or complete answer. I try do that but i cant resolve this problem.